# Target a specific indirect parent class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I've 2 (or more) divs called `hidden_block`. I cannot change the HTML and I have to use jQuery, even though I've just started to learn javascript but I don't have any choice on this one.

I'd like that when you click on `slider_head` the `hidden_content` block just below gets displayed but only the `hidden_content` from the involved `hidden_block` div.

My codepen and html/jquery code:
https://codepen.io/HollowKnight/pen/bOEzay

```js
$(function slideBlock() {
  $('.hidden_content').hide();
  $('.slider_head').on("click", function() {
    var sliderhead = $(this);
    var hiddenblock = $(sliderhead).parent();
    if ((hiddenblock > '.hidden_content').is(':hidden')) {
      $(hiddenblock > '.hidden_content').slideDown(500);
    } else {
      $(hiddenblock > '.hidden_content').slideUp(1000);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hidden_block">
  <span class="slider_head">PARTIE 1 TEST</span>
  <div class="hidden_content">
    <p>test test test</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="hidden_block">
  <span class="slider_head">PARTIE 2</span>
  <div class="hidden_content">
    <p>test2 test2 test2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in your question is flawed because you're comparing a jQuery object to a string. It seems like it's a typo anyway, as I presume `>` should be the descendent selector, not a greater than operator. Also note that in several cases in the CodePen (which appears to have different code to the question) you are selecting a jQuery object, then later on wrapping that in a jQuery object again, which should be avoided.

To do what you require you can simply select the sibling `.hidden_content` and hide/show it as needed:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".hidden_content").hide();
  $(".slider_head").on("click", function() {
    var $sliderhead = $(this);
    var $hiddenblock = $sliderhead.siblings('.hidden_content');

    if ($hiddenblock.is(":hidden")) {
      $hiddenblock.slideDown(500);
    } else {
      $hiddenblock.slideUp(1000);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hidden_block">
  <span class="slider_head">PARTIE 1 TEST</span>
  <div class="hidden_content">
    <p>test test test</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="hidden_block">
  <span class="slider_head">PARTIE 2</span>
  <div class="hidden_content">
    <p>test2 test2 test2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also note that this can be further simplified to use `slideToggle()` instead of checking the state of the element before showing it:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".hidden_content").hide();
  $(".slider_head").on("click", function() {
    $(this).siblings('.hidden_content').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hidden_block">
  <span class="slider_head">PARTIE 1 TEST</span>
  <div class="hidden_content">
    <p>test test test</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="hidden_block">
  <span class="slider_head">PARTIE 2</span>
  <div class="hidden_content">
    <p>test2 test2 test2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what i wanted, and thanks for the explanations btw.

Comment: No problem, glad to help